# Merging an associalive array by specific value not working

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I would like to merge the `$my_array` by **group_order** value.

**Intitial `$my_array` structure:**

```
array(4) {
  array(1) { 
    object(stdClass) {
      ["title"]=> string(23) "Title 1"
      ["group_order"]=> string(1) "2"
    }
  }
  array(1) {
    object(stdClass) {
      ["title"]=> string(32) "Title 2"
      ["group_order"]=> string(1) "1"
    }
  }
  array(1) {
    object(stdClass) {
      ["title"]=> string(21) "Title 3"
      ["group_order"]=> string(1) "1"
    }
  }
  array(1) {
    object(stdClass) {
      ["title"]=> string(23) "Title 4"
      ["group_order"]=> string(1) "2"
    }
  }
}
```

**Desired result:**

```
array(2) {
  array(2) { 
    object(stdClass) {
      ["title"]=> string(23) "Title 1"
      ["group_order"]=> string(1) "2"
    }
    object(stdClass) {
      ["title"]=> string(23) "Title 4"
      ["group_order"]=> string(1) "2"
    }
  }
  array(2) {
    object(stdClass) {
      ["title"]=> string(32) "Title 2"
      ["group_order"]=> string(1) "1"
    }
    object(stdClass) {
      ["title"]=> string(21) "Title 3"
      ["group_order"]=> string(1) "1"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to do it this way:

```
foreach ($my_array as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        $grouped[$item->group_order] = $row;
    }
}
```

But the second group element is always overwiriting the first one, and instead of array with 4 items, there's two. I tried **array_merge()** as well, but the outcome is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding empty brackets `[]` at the end in order to append values to the array, and not overwrite them.

```
foreach ($my_array as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        $grouped[$item->group_order][] = $item;
    }
}
```

Comment: With : $grouped[$item->group_order][] = $item; //not row

Answer (score 0):

You added a foreach you didn't need for some reason? And to keep them seperate just give them a id.

```
$i=0;
foreach ($myarray as $item) {
    $grouped[$item->group_order][$i] = $item;
    $i++;
}
```